# Why is rails object showing up in e-mail sent via ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am practicing ROR4 with the Pragmatic Agile Rails development book. In it, there's a section about sending email via ActionMailer. Although I am able to send email, I am unable to remove the eppended Rails object, as shown below, in the highlighted area:[image]
(`LineItem` is a model, used to store quantity of `Product` that buyer puts in `Cart`)

---

these are the contents of my files:

```
// order_notifier.rb = my email sender model
class OrderNotifier < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "username@domain.com"

  def received(order)
    @order=order
    mail to: @order.email, subject: 'Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation'
  end

  def shipped
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end

// recieved.html.erb = the mail that will be sent 
<h3>PragmaticOrderShipped</h3>
<p>This is just to let you know that we've shipped your recent order:</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
    <%=@order.line_items.each do |o_li|%>
        <tr>
            <td><%=Product.find(o_li.product_id).title%></td>
            <td><%=o_li.quantity%></td>
        </tr>
    <%end%>
</table>
```

---

Can Someone please tell me, why is the `LineItem` thing showing up in the final email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your ERB file, remove the `=` sign from the `@order.line_items.each`:

```
<% @order.line_items.each do |o_li|  %>
```

That will cause the model object to be printed in addition to the block executing.

Comment: Can also change `<td><%=Product.find(o_li.product_id).title%></td>` to `<td><%= o_li.product.title %></td>` if you want some code re-factor.

Comment: @NitinVerma - yes. i forgot at the moment of asking the question that product belongs_to line_items too. Silly me.